# Databricks: Inserting an argument into the LIKE-clause of a query in a %sql cell

Tags: databricks

In a Databricks-notebook, I have a widget that allows to set a value for the argument `kw`. I need to use that value in a query as part of a LIKE-clause. The snippet below runs, but doesn't return anything (even when it should).

```
%sql

SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE keyword LIKE '%getArgument("kw")%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
%sql

SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE keyword LIKE '%$kw%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the 'kw' represents but I think it should be:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM SomeTable  WHERE SomeField LIKE CONCAT('%', kw, '%')")
```

Use the appropriate libraries:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc) // Make sure you use HiveContext
import sqlContext.implicits._

sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM SomeTable  WHERE SomeField LIKE CONCAT('%', kw, '%')")
```

Comment: within a `%sql`-cell, this produces the following error: 
`cannot resolve 'kw' `